# MySQL on Docker - "Found existing redo log files, but at least one is missing"

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, innodb

I'm running a MySQL container using Docker and Docker Compose. My setup includes, in addition to MySQL, an Apache/PHP server and PHPmyadmin, all of them part of the same multi-container app created with Docker Compose.

I've been using this setup for a few months now, and everything was working fine until recently. For some reason, the MySQL container keeps starting and restarting continuously, which makes me unable to access my databases.

Here is the execution log:

```
2023-03-27 22:31:19 2023-03-27 21:31:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
2023-03-27 22:31:20 2023-03-27 21:31:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-03-27 22:31:20 2023-03-27 21:31:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
2023-03-27 22:31:21 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2023-03-27 22:31:21 2023-03-27T21:31:21.723016Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-03-27 22:31:21 2023-03-27T21:31:21.744146Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2023-03-27 22:31:21 2023-03-27T21:31:21.744174Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 1
2023-03-27 22:31:21 2023-03-27T21:31:21.809687Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-03-27 22:31:23 2023-03-27T21:31:23.338669Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013893] [InnoDB] Found existing redo log files, but at least one is missing. It is unknown if recovery could reach physically consistent state. Please consider restoring from backup or providing --innodb-force-recovery > 0.
2023-03-27 22:31:23 2023-03-27T21:31:23.338765Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-03-27 22:31:23 2023-03-27T21:31:23.721887Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-03-27 22:31:23 2023-03-27T21:31:23.722344Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-03-27 22:31:23 2023-03-27T21:31:23.722413Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-03-27 22:31:23 2023-03-27T21:31:23.724842Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

It seems that the error is caused by missing redo log files, but as I'm relatively inexperienced with MySQL, I'm unsure what I should do to try and solve this. I'm running Windows 11, Docker 4.17.1 and MySQL 8.0.32.